# What is practical difference between `inline` and `template<class = void>`?

Tags: c++

We have 2 methods to declare function in header-only library. They are `inline` and  `template<class = void>`. In [`boost` source code](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/boost/beast/core/detail/base64.hpp) I can see both variants. Example follows:

```
inline void my_header_only_function(void)
{
   // Do something...
   return;
}

template<class = void> void my_header_only_function(void)
{
   // Do something...
   return;
}
```

I know what is difference according to C++ standard. However, any C++ compiler is much more than just standard, and also standard is unclear often.

In situation where template argument is never used and where it is not related to recursive variadic template, is there (and what is) **practical** difference between 2 variants for mainstream compilers?

Comment: I fail to see where the template solution is better than the inline one.

Comment: Did `// Do something...` contain any static variables?

Comment: And can you see where it is practically worse?

Comment: @StoryTeller I have no idea, what if it contains?

Comment: Then `my_header_only_function<int>`, `my_header_only_function<char>`, and `my_header_only_function<>` are three separate inline functions that implement the same logic but operate on different static data.

Comment: "In boost source code I can see both variants" - I think it would be better to post those variants, I feel like something is missing here

Comment: I could see one difference being that the inlining scores might be different, but a library going to those lengths would be news to me.

Comment: @StoryTeller You are right, template variant may be misused and it is supposed to be disadvantage.

Comment: @VTT see this https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/boost/beast/core/detail/base64.hpp `base64_encode` is inline, other ones are templates.

Comment: @Vitaliy: it's worse because it allows a fake non-used parameter for no reason.

Comment: @Vitaliy - Where did I say it's misuse?

Comment: @StoryTeller You didn't say, but it is how I understand it; why do we need 3 separate functions with no observable difference?

Comment: @Vitaliy - They have different side effects (their static data is separate). Why someone may *need* to use templates as a code generation tool like that, IDK. But the option is there ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @chris, as far as I understand mainstream compilers ignore `inline` keyword often and in practice do inline on theirs own discretion. Real inlining depend on optimization level much more that on keyword; keyword is just hint, so I am not sure whether compiler will inline the function and will not inline template in practice.

Comment: @Vitaliy, Yes, compilers ultimately do it at their own discretion. Putting the keyword doesn't guarantee inlining, but as far as I've seen, commonly bumps up the score the compiler assigns, which can potentially push it past the inlining threshold. Again, it seems rather dubious to avoid the keyword for that reason.

Comment: @Vitaly: The `inline` keyword doesn't _necessarily_ have to be there because the author wanted the function to be inlined. Since this appears in a header and headers are usually included many times (the number being unknown in advance), you need to be careful of ODR. Without `inline`, you're in trouble.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this can be used as a weird way to allow library extension (or mocking) from outside library code by providing specialization for `void` or a non-template version of the function in the same namespace:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class = void>
int
foo(int data)
{
    ::std::cout << "template" << std::endl;
    return data;
}
// somewhere else
int
foo(int data)
{
    ::std::cout << "non-template" << std::endl;
    return data;
}

int main()
{
    foo(1); // non template overload is selected
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lpToSixojzMGjwX9)

Comment: It looks like you are right, I didn't think about that. For sure it is practical difference, we can override template with inline or non-inline function.

Comment: For that to work the library must must never form a fully qualified name itself. And since it's for a built-in type, ADL won't work. So "extending" the library in question doesn't look like a compelling reason. Furthermore user code can always pick and choose with the help of namespaces.

Comment: @StoryTeller: nothing stops you from putting the mocked version into the same namespace as the original one.

Comment: Or fully specialization instead of overload.

Comment: @geza - Really? Does `boost` make guarantees about its behavior if declarations are added into its namespace?

Comment: @Jarod42 The boost itself seem to always call such functions with default template parameters.

Comment: @VTT - Yes, but user code an declare `foo<void>` and the specialization would be picked. If you incorporate that into your answer (along with a namespace) it will make more sense.

Comment: I mean that `template <> int
foo<void>(int data) {mock();}` is an alternative to `int
foo(int data) {mock();}`. but both ways are risky with ODR or is partial mocking [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lpToSixojzMGjwX9).

Comment: @StoryTeller: I don't know any such guarantees. But boost is not a special namespace, this technique should work most of the cases. If boost don't use `template <class=void>` because of "mockability", then what could be reason? They even mix `inline` and `template <class=void>` in the same file.

Comment: @geza - Neither is `std` a "special" namespace. Those restrictions are imposed to prevent libraries and user code from stepping on each other's toes. So "works in most cases" isn't refuting much. And just because this answer offers a nice explanation doesn't mean it's **the** explanation for boost itself.

Comment: Well, for `boost` the explanation may be simple negligence; `base64` is ported to `boost` from another library where the approach might have sence, in `boost` they might just don't care about that.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Sure. I didn't ask "what could be the reason", because I'm sure that VTT's answer the reason. I'm curious, if not "mockability" the reason, then what could be?

Comment: @Vitaliy: boost uses this technique at other places as well.

Comment: @geza - Who said there is one well thought out reason? Do they **document it** as an extension point? Because if one thing boost does well it is document extension points.

Comment: @StoryTeller: it's just a question, please :) I didn't say that there must be a well thought out reason. Even didn't asked it this way. But maybe there's some reason behind this. If someone needs an inline function, they will use `inline`, and not `template <class=void>`. There must be some (any) reason that they choose `template <class=void>` instead of the shorter `inline`.

Comment: @geza - You didn't ask that as a question. *"Sure. I didn't ask "what could be the reason", because I'm sure that VTT's answer the reason"* - your own words. The question you did pose just tried to frame this as black and white. Now, as fun as debating these logical fallacies is, it's best if we both just move. I'm signing off, feel free to have the last word.

Comment: @StoryTeller Well, `std` *is* a "special" namespace because the standard explicitly makes most cases of putting stuff inside `std` Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @Angew - It's special to the standard. If boost was to take a similar stance with its namespace, would it somehow be less undefined? No. Undefined is undefined.

Answer (score 8):

One difference is that binary code for the function may become part of the generated object file even if the function is never used in that file, but there will *never* be any code for the template if it's not used.

Comment: Can you please write any reference that proofs that any compiler will not discard unused function from binary file on optimization stage?

Comment: @Vitaliy Not really, that's why I wrote "may become", not "will become."

Comment: It is reasonably common that compilers don't remove unused functions - it sort of breaks the separate compilation model, which means a function defined in one compilation unit needs to be called from another.   Very few linkers (the program that combine objects into an executable) even check that any functions which are defined are never used, let alone remove unused functions.      Whereas the compiler does not emit code for a template UNLESS the template is either used (resulting in implicit instantiation) or explicitly instantiated.

Comment: @Peter: compilers don't emit code for non-used inline functions either. At least, I've never see one.

Comment: In that particular boost header all those template functions are always immediately instantiated to be used in non-template functions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of Beast. Hopefully I will be able to shed some light on why you see one versus the other. It really is very simple, the template seems less likely to be inlined into calling functions, bloating the code needlessly. I know that "inline" is really only supposed to mean "remove duplicate definitions" but sometimes compiler implementors get overzealous. The template thing is a little bit harder on the compile (Travis craps out sometimes at only 2GB RAM). So I decided to try writing some new stuff using the "inline" keyword. I still don't know how I feel about it.

The short answer is that I was doing it one way for a long time and then I briefly did it the other way for no particularly strong reason. Sorry if that is not as exciting as the other theories! (which were very interesting in fact)

Comment: Why not use `BOOST_NOINLINE` then?